# Recovering deleted SAM and SECURITY files on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Locked out of my laptop, forgot my password...  Removed the hard drive and plugged it in to my desktop with a SATA to USB cord and deleted the SAM file as well as the security file.  Then like a jackASS I emptied my recycling bin because I am OCD with that thing, lesson learned but what do I do now?  Dealing with windows 7 on a Gateway Intel ATOM.  Small laptop type thing with Starter 7 on it.  My Desk top is using XP.

Answer (score 1):

A backup copy should be located in \Windows\System32\config\RegBack on that drive. Copy \Windows\System32\config\RegBack\SAM back to its original location. You'll find SECURITY there as well.

You may also wish to try and undelete the original files first, since they are more current than the backups. Try [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva) (free, trustworthy, works well) to see if you can undelete it from the drive ASAP. Do not write anything else to that drive before you do, if possible (if you try this I would try it before attempting the backup recovery described above). If you recently deleted it and have not done much else with the drive your chances for recovery are good.